# Regex.Replace not replacing

Tags: c#, regex

I have am using regex.replace to replace a '#' character with a Environment.Newline.
However it is not returning the expected results. It is just returning the same input string.
Here is my code.

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"#", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Did you try `var result = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"#", Environment.NewLine);`?

Comment: Why not use string.Replace instead in such a simple case?

Comment: That is what I ended up using. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` doesn't change the parameter you passed in. It returns the results as a new string.

Try this:

```
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"#", Environment.NewLine);
```

Of course, Regex is a bit overkill for such a simple replacement. `String.Replace` would be enough in that case (note: `String.Replace` also doesn't modify the parameter, but returns a new string).

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, that is it. It's only Thrusday morning and it has been a long day! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `RegEx` for what you're doing, simpler:

```
inputString = inputString.Replace("#", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dr. ABT mentioned, you need to return the `Replace` method into a variable.  So, you could do:

`inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"#",Environment.NewLine);`

This will update the `inputString` variable with the required replacements.